# С дублировать контролер не получается

Tags: php, laravel

```
    public function posts($id)
{
    $posts = Post::where('category_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(12);
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $menu_id = $category->id;
    $year = 'created_at';
    return view('posts',compact('posts','category','menu_id'));
}
public function oldposts($id)
{
    $posts = Post::where('category_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(12);
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $menu_id = $category->id;
    return view('oldposts',compact('oldposts','category','menu_id'));
}
```

выдает ошибку(1/1) ErrorException
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::oldposts()

```
Route::get('oldposts', 'HomeController@oldposts');
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'HomeController@posts');
```

Работает posts/15  хочу разделить старые и новые новости
хочу в олд поставить старые <= 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем столько дублирования из-за 1 параметра? Можно же сделать необязательный параметр, к примеру `sort` или любой другой и вышло бы вот так:

```
public function posts($id, $sort = null)
{
    $posts = Post::where('category_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(12);
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $menu_id = $category->id;
    if ($sort !== null) { // можно добавить больше логики своей
        $year = 'created_at';
    }
    return view('posts',compact('posts','category','menu_id'));
}
```

Роут был бы один:

```
Route::get('posts/{id}/{sort?}', 'HomeController@posts');
```

И так же вьюхи не нужно дублировать, тогда бы `url` был бы:

> `posts/15` - для новых
>
> `posts/15/old` - для старых (вместо old можно что угодно написать, к примеру `posts/15/2018`, потом в action от этого значения фильтр делать)

P.S. А вообще не вижу фильтр в экшене с разделением на старые и новые посты.

Comment: И спасибо большое вам обоим)

Comment: $oldi = (substr("$item->created_at", 0, 4))
Вот хочу теперь сделать что бы можете подсказать как отборку по годам сделать еще?
@if($category->id == 15) || ($oldi =>2018)

Answer (score 2):

Вы в роутах не указали параметр /{id}

```
Route::get('oldposts/{id}', 'HomeController@oldposts');
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'HomeController@posts');
```